# How to load react application based on country

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I have a React application running in India. All the APIs are in a constant file (example: endpointConstants.js). Now, I have to use a different set of endpoints for other countries. How do I detect the country and decide which set of endpoints to be used based in the coutry? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

One of approaches could be:

You could use your backend or one of third-party services to detect the country (there are plenty of them, like https://ipdata.co, https://www.geoapify.com/ip-geolocation-api). Then, you should create a key-map of endpoints for different locations, for example:

```
export const endpoints = {
   India: {
     loginAPI: '/api/india-login/
   },
   USA: {
     loginAPI: '/api/usa-login/
   }
}
```

And when your app starts you check the country using solutions above and save the country key to LocalStorage, for example. Then, when you make api requests you get the country key from LocalStorage and get your endpoints set, like `endpoints[countryKey]` and use the right set for the particular country.